# Problems to receive JSON from https server on Android

Tags: android, json, ssl, https

this is my question/problem:

I'm making a URL request to a server that authenticates by SSL through https, but when I get the answer always returns empty when I convert the input to string.
Another call without parameters always runs smoothly

Any ideas?

URL: https://www.server.com/api/getResources.php?res[]=Argentina&res[]=Australia&res[]=Bolivia

And the code:

```
HttpURLConnection http = conectar(URL);
    InputStream urlInputStream = null;
    try {
        urlInputStream = http.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
```

conectar method:

```
private HttpURLConnection conectar(String surl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(surl);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

    }

    HttpURLConnection http = null;

    if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
        trustEveryone();
        HttpsURLConnection https = null;
        try {
            https = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        // https.setHostnameVerifier(DO_NOT_VERIFY);
        http = https;
    } else {
        try {
            http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
    return http;
}
```

trustEveryone method:

```
HttpsURLConnection
                .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname,
                            SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); // TLS
        context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                    String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        } }, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
                .getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Another call without parameters always runs smoothly

Comment: The problem is very strange because it is specifically that call that does not work, I see, if I call other files, including calls with parameters not given me any problems

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL string you posted correct?  If so you need to encode the square brackets before passing it into the `URL` constructor.  The [documentation for `URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) states:

> The URL class does not itself encode or decode any URL components according to the escaping mechanism defined in RFC2396. It is the responsibility of the caller to encode any fields, which need to be escaped prior to calling URL, and also to decode any escaped fields, that are returned from URL

**EDIT**
[RFC2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) states that:

> Data corresponding to excluded characters must be escaped in order to be properly represented within a URI.

The square brackets are counted as excluded characters.

As such you need to encode the parameter string prior to including it in the URL.  You don't want to encode the whole URL as otherwise it will encode characters such as `:`.  Here is a code snippet:

```
String parameters = "res[]=Argentina&res[]=Australia&res[]=Bolivia";
String encodedParameters = URLEncoder.encode(parameters , "UTF-8");
```

You can then append this to your host & path and pass it into your `URL` constructor.

Comment: Yes, the URL is correct.
Could you give an example? thank you very much

Comment: Ok,thanks for the expample, I've tested and should work but no.
Another thing I tried is to do the query with http (not https) and it works correctly.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Jorge Garrido Do you have control over the server code?  If so I'd start of with a single simple parameter `test=value`.  See if this works, if so, build up to the more complex one.

Comment: Yes, I tried it with parameters and without parameters and nothing, I keep getting 0

Comment: @Jorge Garrido I'm confused, as previously you stated that a call without parameters "runs smoothly".  Can you edit your question to list exactly which URLs work and which fail?